# Cosa significa "essere a una buona mira" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Venni presto in chiaro del perché lavoravano cosí da demoni e tiravano tanto la cinghia, da un discorso d’interesse che si fecero dietro la casa Tobia e suo figlio piú vecchio. Io ero lí per mio conto, che guardavo il rittano di Sant’Elena e aspettavo che da dentro mi chiamassero a mangiare, quando girano la casa Tobia e suo figlio Jano. Si sedettero sui talloni, il vecchio sputò in terra, il figlio sputò sul bagnato del padre, di nuovo sputò Tobia e di nuovo Jano. 
>         Poi Tobia disse: – **Siamo a una buona mira**, Jano. 
>         – Ma se lo dicevi già quando m’hai messo al mondo! 
>         – Ti dico che adesso **siamo a una buona mira**.
>          – E per quando sarebbe?
>         – Tu adesso dovresti avere quasi diciannove anni. Be’, per quel giorno glorioso non sarai ancora un uomo.
>         – Ma io sono un uomo già adesso!
>         Tobia si mise a ridere: – Sí che sei già un uomo. Tu non sei mio figlio, sei il mio avvocato. Senti qui cosa ho io nella mia mente –. Ma proprio allora la padrona mise le mani all’inferriata della cucina e ci gridò d’entrare a mangiare. Tobia le urlò: – Aspetta, bagascia. Stiamo parlando tra noi uomini –. E poi disse a Jano: – Ho in mente una dozzina di giornate, non di piú, ma tutte a solatio, da tenere mezze a grano e mezze a viti. Con una riva da legna e anche un pratolino da mantenerci due pecore e una mula. Per concimarlo basterà la cenere del forno.
>         – E dove sarebbe questa terra?
>         Tobia si alzò sui ginocchi per tirare piú comodo un peto e poi si riabbassò: – Mica qui, mica su questa langa porca che ti piglia la pelle a montarla prima che a lavorarla. Io me la sogno su una di quelle collinette chiare subito sopra Alba, dove la neve ha appena toccato che già se ne va.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "mira" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può avere il significato figurato di scopo, intenzione, disegno, fine a cui si vuol giungere, ma non sono sicura di averne capito il senso nel brano sopra citato: il fine a cui volevano giungere questi due personaggi, cioè, l'acquisto di questa terra tra un po' di tempo, era buono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato ***essere ad una buona mira*** significa essere a buon punto con i propri propositi.

In un altro passaggio dello stesso libro:

> Voi non mi crederete, ma sono a una **mira** che sto pensando d’imparare a
>   suonare il clarinetto per guadagnarmi qualcosa nelle feste. Stemmo a
>   vederlo andarsene col cadreghino sulla spalla, e quel giorno capii che
>   i preti giovani somigliano un po’ a noi servitori, hanno fortuna o
>   sfortuna a seconda dei parroci che imbroccano, preciso a noi coi
>   nostri padroni”.

Qui si può intendere che mira ha il significato di punto:

> Voi non mi crederete, ma sono a *un punto* che sto pensando d’imparare a
>   suonare il clarinetto per guadagnarmi qualcosa nelle feste.

Ho trovato anche un estratto del libro, [*Il sacrificio di Agostino*](https://www.edatlas.it/documents/1f315a6f-f4dd-4e39-b59b-b01a40eefd5b), dove vengono anche descritti i piemontesismi e i termini più difficili da capire:

> Come la mia famiglia sia scesa alla **mira**(6) di mandare un figlio, me, a
>   servire lontano da casa, è un fatto che forse io sono ancora troppo
>   giovane per capirlo da me solo.

nelle note di piè di pagina si legge:

> 6. sia scesa alla mira: piemontesismo, si sia ridotta nella condizione.

cioè sia arrivata al punto di mandare un figlio...

Un modo alternativo per esprimere lo stesso concetto è l'espressione [essere a tiro](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tiro_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/):

> ▲ Locuz. prep.: fig., **a tiro**, a un tiro di schioppo [che è
>   raggiungibile con facilità: *essere a un t. di schioppo*] ≈ a due passi,
>   a portata di mano, nelle vicinanze, vicino.

Un altro modo di dire simile può essere anche [essere a cavallo](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/cavallo.shtml), cioè:

> indicativo di floride prospettive economiche conquistate però con
>   sacrificio.

Comment: abarisone, è possibile che sia corretto, ma ogni tanto non capisco bene le tue risposte: dici, in sostanza, A significa B o C e poi porti fonti su B e C, quando invece sarebbero più utili quelle su A, no?

Comment: In effetti ogni tanto non le capisco bene anche io... :-)) Comunque appena mi è possibile miglioro la risposta

Comment: Hai promesso un miglioramento della tua risposta: lo sto aspettando.

Comment: Non ho trovato direttamente una fonte esterna per _essere ad una buona mira_ ma ho trovato un altro passaggio nello stesso libro che fa capire che _mira_ è usata con il significato di _punto_.

Comment: Ma, veramente il significato di "mira" in questi due passaggi è lo stesso? Devo dire che non capisco neanche il senso di "mira" nel passaggio che hai citato.

Comment: Il significato è essere ad un (buon) punto in entrambi i casi.

Comment: [Questo articolo](https://dial.uclouvain.be/downloader/downloader.php?pid=boreal:81491&datastream=PDF_01) conferma che "alla mira" in questo romanzo di Fenoglio significa "al punto".

Comment: «L’influsso 
del dialetto ha lasciato delle tracce anche nel lessico de *La malora*; Fenoglio utilizza 
“censa” invece di “privativa”, “stroppo” invece di “branco”, “onta” invece di “vergogna”, 
“particolare” invece di “piccolo possidente”, “bricco” invece di “monte”, “rubarizio” invece di “furto”, “diffizioso” invece di “schizzinoso”, “sversa” invece di “contrariata”, “alla mira” invece di “al punto”, “genare” invece di “imbarazzare”, “schivare” invece di “tener da parte” e “sbardati” invece di “sparpagliati” (tutti questi esempi secondo Grignani, 97).»